# Passing dynamic filters to created Index in Lucene Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have created Lucene index from my project & Querying & filtering working if condition filter is hard-coded, so while searching it's getting only matched filtered word & in that i am going to search. And now I wanted to pass filter based on my requirement & i don't want to hard code the filter condition. for example I'll pass the filter like Student Should belong particular department & he/she should be taken particular some subjects using sql will write like

```
select * from dbo.[Student] where departmentId=1 
                            and subject ='history'
```

and IO acheived this using binaryquery. Now I wanted pass filter like

```
select * from dbo.[Student] where departmentId=1 
                            and subject in('history','general') 
                            and (class='5sem' or class='6sem')
```

or

```
select * from dbo.[Student] where subject in('history','general') 
                            and departmentId=1 and (class='5sem' or class='6sem')
```

Search method

public DataSet Search(string criterion, string term, string filter){
           Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\LuceneIndex"));
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

```
        BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();

        IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, true);
        Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

        var queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, criterion, analyzer);

        queryParser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;

        var query = queryParser.Parse(term.ToLower() + "*");

        bq.Add(query, Occur.MUST);
        foreach (string str in filter.Split(','))
        {
            if (str.Split('$').Length == 3)
            {
                if (str.Split('$')[1] == "=")
                {
                    bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term(str.Split('$')[0], (str.Split('$')[2]).ToLower())), Occur.MUST);
                }
                else if (str.Split('$')[1] == "<>")
                {
                    bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term(str.Split('$')[0], (str.Split('$')[2]).ToLower())), Occur.MUST_NOT);
                }
            }
        }

        TopDocs resultDocs = searcher.Search(bq, null, indexReader.MaxDoc, Sort.RELEVANCE);

        var topDocs = resultDocs.ScoreDocs;

        DataSet Students = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("UAN");
        dt.Columns.Add("Firstname");
        DataRow row = null;
        foreach (var hit in topDocs)
        {
            var documentFromSerach = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
            row = dt.NewRow();
            row["UAN"] = documentFromSerach.Get("UAN");
            row["FirstName"] = documentFromSerach.Get("FirstName");
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        Students.Tables.Add(dt);

        return Students;
    }
```

On Seach button click
StudentLuceneIndex.StudentLuceneIndexSearch obj = new StudentLuceneIndex.StudentLuceneIndexSearch();
DataSet ds = obj.Search("All", "*" + textBox1.Text.Trim(), "departmentid$=$1,subject$=$history");

How to achieve this type of filter in lucene.net?

Comment: would be nice if you provide what code you've tried!

Comment: Without seeing the indexing code...
Lucene field names are case sensitive. The values _might_ be too, depending on the analyzer used. Looking at the names in the foreach you're capitalizing them. But your search syntax is all lower case.
The names must match exactly.